# MySQL alias IF statements

Tags: mysql

How do you query something like

```
if parent = 0 then alias is network_id else alias is group_id
```

Is this possible with only queries?

Comment: You can't have a single result column that's renamed to two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't arbitrarily rename a result column, as all results must have identical column names, the closest thing is this:

```
SELECT IF(parent = 0, id, NULL) AS network_id,
  IF(parent != 0, id, NULL) AS group_id
  FROM ...
```

This will only populate one of `network_id` or `group_id` depending on your logic. Both columns must be present in all rows, though, as the columns are common for the entire result set.

Comment: Did this and just used php to unset nulls from the array. resulting to either showing network_id or group_id

Comment: Once you have it as arrays on the PHP side you can do whatever you want. MySQL uses a rigid results format that can't be manipulated like this independently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement.

```
select 
 ( case when parent=0 then network_id else group_id end ) as 'xyz_id'
```

Example:

```
mysql> select date1,
        case when date1='2013-11-26'
                  then date_format(date1, '%d %M %Y')
             when date1='2013-11-27'
                  then 'new date literal'
             else date1
        end as 'dt' 
       from dates;
+------------+------------------+
| date1      | dt               |
+------------+------------------+
| 2013-11-26 | 26 November 2013 |
| 2013-11-27 | new date literal |
| 2013-11-29 | 2013-11-29       |
| 2013-11-30 | 2013-11-30       |
| 2013-12-01 | 2013-12-01       |
+------------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: What if I want the ALIASES to be different, not the actual data.

Comment: @madziikoy use a literal there.

Comment: But how do i set the literal?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I want to show a different column alias based on a condition